# Any Dua(s) To Stop Or Reduce Nocturnal Emissions

Tags: nocturnal-emission

Salam
I am A Teen Boy, And I Have Been Having Constant Nocturnal Emissions For The Past 2 Years (Even Sometimes Waking Up 3 Times In One Night), however, these Days because the schools are open and start earlier, i am unable to catch my Sleep plus these days i have them while i am sleeping on my stomach, which means the whole bed sheet and bed needs to be washed, and i feel bad for my Mother, Have been to several doctors but nothing seems to work, does anyone know any Dua Or Any Surah That I Should Recite Before Sleeping to Stop This, Pls Answer As Now its starting to effect my everyday life
(I Dont Watch Any NSFW Stuff, nor Do I Masturbate)

Comment: Why should somebody want something ton stop which is natural and given by Allah.

Comment: Bcoz its starting to effect my daily life....i wouldnt mind it happening 2 or 3 times a month but 5/6 a week Is just ridiculous

Answer (score 1):

Listen boy!  This is a thing you and we (male men) can't control. Allah 'azzawajal created us like this way. THIS is a very common and very normal thing in male especially when they are hitting puberty. There is "***NOTHING***" can help us to stop having nocturnal emissions or wet dreams, really! I'm not kidding! It’s our nature. Some boys have nocturnal emissions  a few times a week, some have them only a couple throughout their life!!!!
There is nothing wrong with having more wet dreams or not having nocturnal emissions at all!!!  Having nocturnal emission/wet dream is a normal part of growing up. So, you must not feel guilty or ashamed about having them a lot.

Now what Medical-science tells us about wet dream/nocturnal emission is that wet dreams/nocturnal emissions  are caused by a rise in levels of the hormone "***testosterone***" that happens in a guy's body during puberty. *Having them is a pretty common sign of puberty. They aren't a sign of a health problem or diseases. The most important thing is that they don't cause any harm. However, they can be confusing and embarrassing at first. Don't  panic.*

### Now let me suggest you to do a couple of things as precaution

1/ Try sleeping with a ***towel*** nearby.

2/ If you're sleeping at a friend's house/ your relative's house, have a change of underwear with you.

3/ ***Avoiding sleeping on your stomach.***

4/ Always urinate before sleeping.

✪5/ ***Avoid masturbation strictly***. (In islam, masturbation is totally prohibited).

✪6/ ***Avoid watching *porn***. (Watching porn, erotic stories, audio porn, sfw, nsfw are ➤ **Prohibited in islam**).

7/ ***Amorous thoughts and discussions must be avoided***.

8/ ***Daily exercise should be done***. This is very important. Take care of your body shape. Don't be a fat flabby guy!! Make your body strong and fit. What about having a ***six pack abs***!!! Build your bicep like an egg. Try to do ***~100 push ups*** daily! Invest your time on working out. You can ***follow these YouTube channels***
☞ https://youtube.com/c/IvanRusakov

☞ https://youtube.com/c/JeremyEthier

☞ https://youtube.com/c/athleanx

https://youtube.com/channel/UC_nfjMmJlJXrhl2xbP9wwgRA

☞ https://youtube.com/user/FitnessFAQs

### [Islamic prescription] must be followed in  daily basis

1/ ***Go to bed early***. Prophet Mohammed (may peace and blessings of Allah be upon him)
***disliked it to stay awake after Isha prayer*** without any necessity.

> ✔**Abu Barza reported: رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ
> وَسَلَّمَ كَانَ يَكْرَهُ النَّوْمَ قَبْلَ الْعِشَاءِ وَالْحَدِيثَ
> بَعْدَهَا The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him,
> disliked to sleep before the evening prayer and to talk after it.
> Source: Sahih Bukhari 543, Grade: Sahih**
>
> ✔**Aisha reported: مَا نَامَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ
> وَسَلَّمَ قَبْلَ الْعِشَاءِ وَلَا سَمَرَ بَعْدَهَا The Messenger of
> Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, would not sleep before the
> evening prayer and he would not stay up after it. Source: Sunan Ibn
> Majah 702, Grade: Sahih**

2/ It is recommended to ***perform ablution before going to sleep***.

> ✔**Ibn Umar reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be
> upon him, said: مَنْ بَاتَ طَاهِرًا بَاتَ فِي شِعَارِهِ مَلَكٌ فَلَمْ
> يَسْتَيْقِظْ إِلا قَالَ الْمَلَكُ اللَّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لِعَبْدِكَ فُلانٍ
> فَإِنَّهُ بَاتَ طَاهِرًا Whoever goes to sleep in a state of purity
> will have an angel over his head and he will not awaken until the
> angel says: O Allah, forgive your servant for he has slept with
> ablution. Source: Sahih Ibn Hibban 1064, Grade: Sahih**

3/ It is recommended to pray the voluntary ***witr prayer (salat al-witr) before sleep.***

[If you fear that you will not get up at the end of the night you should pray Witr before you go to sleep].

> ✔**Jabir reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon
> him, said, “Whoever fears he cannot stand for prayer at the end of the
> night, let him perform Witr prayer in its beginning. Whoever hopes to
> stand for prayer at the end of the night, let him perform Witr prayer
> at its ending. Verily, prayer at the end of the night is witnessed,
> and that is better.” Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 755 Grade: Sahih
> (authentic) according to Muslim عَنْ جَابِرٍ قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ
> اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ مَنْ خَافَ أَنْ لَا يَقُومَ
> مِنْ آخِرِ اللَّيْلِ فَلْيُوتِرْ أَوَّلَهُ وَمَنْ طَمِعَ أَنْ يَقُومَ
> آخِرَهُ فَلْيُوتِرْ آخِرَ اللَّيْلِ فَإِنَّ صَلَاةَ آخِرِ اللَّيْلِ
> مَشْهُودَةٌ وَذَلِكَ أَفْضَلُ 755 صحيح مسلم كتاب صلاة المسافرين وقصرها
> باب من خاف أن لا يقوم من آخر الليل فليوتر أوله**

4/ It is recommended to perform the ***prophetic supplications before going to sleep***.
You should ***learn and memorize*** all of these adhkar....
https://preciousgemsfromthequranandsunnah.wordpress.com/2018/11/29/authentic-adhkar-before-sleep/

and ***read them Daily beofore going to sleep***.

5/ It is recommended to ***wake up early*** enough to perform the two voluntary cycles of prayer before congregational dawn prayer.

> ✔**Aisha reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon
> him said: رَكْعَتَا الْفَجْرِ خَيْرٌ مِنْ الدُّنْيَا وَمَا فِيهَا [Two
> bowings of prayer before the dawn prayer are better than the world and
> whatever is in it] Source: Sahih Muslim 725, Grade: Sahih**

6/ It is recommended to praise Allah, to remember the Hereafter, and to perform ***supplications after waking up***.

> ✔**Abu Dharr reported: When the Messenger of Allah, peace and
> blessings be upon him, woke up he would say: الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ الَّذِي
> أَحْيَانَا بَعْدَ مَا أَمَاتَنَا وَإِلَيْهِ النُّشُورُ {All praise is
> due to Allah who has given us life after our death and to Him is the
> resurrection} Source: Sahih Bukhari 6960, Grade: Sahih**

So, dear! These are the things that might help you Insh-Allah. And Don't forget to make a lot of dua in your sujood(prostration).

May Allah 'azzawajal help us all in all aspects of our life.

Answer (score -1):

Best solution ever :

Say out loud right before you sleep (on the bed) : **Surat Al-Ikhlass 112, then Surat Al-Falaq 113, then Surat Al-Nas 114, then Ayat Al Kursi (2:255), and lastly the last 2 verses of Surat Al-Baqara**.

I guarantee you 100% that you will not have nightmares and dirty dreams in your sleep. They are nothing but the action of the devil (Shaytan).